# NetCDF data cannot be saved by the GeoServer raster data source

Tags: netcdf, geoserver, era5

My NetCDF file ([ERA5 data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form)) is based on CF convention, with 1-dimensional coordinates.

After browsing the NetCDF file, it cannot be saved by the data source, showing the error below:

```
 There was an error trying to connect to store netcdf_file. Do you want to save it anyway?

Original exception error:

Failed to create reader from file:era5_file.nc and hints Hints: COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@66eb1e17 FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@61dbe424[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@25ad8d63 FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true
```

[GeoServer Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loCdj.png)

GeoServer Version is 2.22, and the GeoServer NetCDF plugin has been installed successfully.

At first, the NetCDF had 4 dimensions (time, level, lat, lon). I changed it to 3-dimention (time, lat, lon). But the problem was not solved.

Access to the NetCDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMGDZx_Eeb5_t2_U-mawzcYH2i2i7LM1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a way for others to reproduce the error.

Comment: You can find the NetCDF file from this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMGDZx_Eeb5_t2_U-mawzcYH2i2i7LM1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You haven't provided anyone with what resulted in the error. All you've said is you used geoserver

Comment: Please take a look at the image

Answer (score 1):

I have no issues publishing the file in GeoServer, e.g:

[image]

and the d2m variable:

[image]

It may be you are storing the NetCDF in a directory where GeoServer cannot add its index files, normally included as hidden sidecar directories.
The [GeoServer NetCDF guide](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/netcdf/netcdf.html#netcdf-files-in-read-only-directories) guide has a section about this case.

Comment: Would you please inform me about your java version.

Comment: I have two java installations: "java-17-openjdk.x86_64" and "java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64". Both of them have the same problem with NetCDF. Also it is interesting that GeoServer can be deployed with both versions. But GeoNetwork cannot be deployed by "java-17-openjdk.x86_64".

Comment: Here's one error indicated by catalina.out file:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver'

Comment: GeoServer runs in an experimental fashion on Java 17. Not recommended. I have been using Java 11.

Comment: I also tried with Java 11 without sucess. I have used https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.22.x/ext-latest/geoserver-2.22-SNAPSHOT-netcdf-plugin.zip. Is it okay or should I add other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that GeoServer 2.23.0 is okay with storing and publishing NetCDF (ERA5 data). I think I just replaced GeoServer 2.22 with 2.23 and added the NetCDF plugin, and also changing to Java 11.

[Published NetCDF (another data) for the variable d2m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whTBH.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).